# Is there a way to change a read-only file system to a writable file system on Mac Catalina?

Tags: command-line, macos-catalina, cp

I'm trying to copy a file from one folder to another folder. I'm getting an error message saying the destination folder is a Read-only file system. I initially thought that changing the file permissions would alleviate the issue, but it did not. What can I do to copy files from one folder to another? Here is the command I used:

```
cp sourceFolder/someFile.txt /destFolder
```

Error message:

```
cp: /destFolder: Read-only file system
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MacOS Catalina has System Integrity Protection or SIP. This needs to be disabled to cp files. To do this I restarted in recovery mode, entered `csrutil disable` into the terminal. Restarted and mounted the file system as write with `sudo mount -uw /`. Then restarted in recovery mode again and `csrutil enable` in terminal and restarted.

Comment: I tried to do the same in Big Sur but getting "mount_apfs: volume could not be mounted: Permission denied" though i am an administrator . Any idea?

Comment: Did you use sudo?

Comment: yes. though it seems they have changed the architecture . more details here. https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOSBeta/comments/he4umc/how_to_make_root_volume_writeable_in_big_sur/